# Why some of God and goddess sitting on Lotus flower?

Tags: gods, symbolism, goddess

As you can see in many pictures of god and goddess sitting or standing on lotus flower.
[image]
[image]

Is there any specific reason on sitting or standing on lotus flower?

And in some pictures of god and goddess shows folded one of their leg while sitting on their respective vahana or on lotus flower.

[image]

What does this signifies?

Comment: One possible spiritual interpretation: The Lotus flower is an example of the best renunciate. It sits cool-ly on muddy water, but is itself totally above the water. Though it is on the water, it is not wet. Though it is in muddy water, it is beautiful! Similarly the great renunciates are those that take part and participate in the world, but they are themselves detached and their beautiful heart is seen, despite the muddy world of which they are involving. All the best sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the cosmic Being came a single lotus of pure gold and with a thousand petals which puts out Brahma who is seated in the center of the golden lotus. In the book *Myths and Symbols of Indian Art and Civilization* it says that the lotus of Brahma represents the highest form of the earth. The filaments of the lotus are the mountains of the world, the outer petals the other continents. In the center of the pericap is the continent of India.

Various gods are shown sitting with one foot down. The foot is down so that devotees can approach the god to offer worship to the particular god.

Lakshmi or Shri is the Lotus Goddess. She first appears in a hymn appended to the Rig Veda. She is associated with the lotus in every way. She is lotus born, lotus standing, lotus colored, lotus thighed, lotus eyed, decked with lotus garlands, etc. Her two sons Mud (kardama) and Moisture (ciklita) are the ingredients for rich soil.

The atman in every person is described as residing in the lotus or cave of the heart. It is said to resemble a closed lotus. When the heart chakra is opened, the golden lotus of the heart opens and the Ishta shines forth.

Comment: can you give source please..

Comment: 1) 1st paragraph - single lotus - Rig veda. Book reference already for rest of paragraph 2) 2nd paragraph - don't remember, from my memory of various books and teachers 3) 3rd paragraph same 2 references as 1st paragraph 4) 4th paragraph various Upanishads

Answer (score 2):

Lotus used as an example of divine **beauty and purity**, Vishnu is often described as the "Lotus-Eyed One".

`he lotus blooms uncovering the creator god Brahma in lotus position.Its unfolding petals suggest the expansion of the soul.`

The growth of its pure beauty from the mud of its origin holds a benign spiritual promise. Particularly Brahma and Lakshmi, the divinities of potency and wealth, have the lotus symbol associated with them.